# Creating a fancy dropdown with varying number of options using angular and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have written the following code for a basic Angular dropdown which takes data from a controller. This creates a very basic dropdown and doesn't utilize Bootstrap styling. I am trying to combine Bootstrap and Angular, but I'm unable to figure out how will I combine the following:

Current code:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li>
                <p>
                    <select data-ng-model="s1" data-ng-options="x.col1 for x in data1" data-ng-change="updateData2()">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Drop Down 1</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
            </li>       
            <li>
                <p>
                    <select data-ng-model="s2" data-ng-options="x.col1 for x in data2" data-ng-change="updateData3()">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Drop Down 1</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
            </li>           
          </ul>
```

What's necessary for Bootstrap:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
```

The problem I'm facing is how to use ng-repeat or another directive, rather than adding `<li>` for every item under ul.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but you should take a look at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown.

Comment: I've followed that and is same as the Bootstrap code I've mentioned. What I'm currently doing is iterating over `data1` and populating the dropdown box items. But when we look at the Bootstrap code it is adding a list item for each option which can't be varied dynamically. I don't have a fixed length for `data1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the thousand foot view of how I implemented this.

Create a JSON object that holds your list items values, attributes and such. You will also need a type property, item, header row, etc.. You will then run the created object through the ng-repeat. While doing the repeat set up a ngSwitch and watch type. Inside of the switch cases you will have a block of HTML that relates to the type it matches. This will let you create several different types of elements inside of the same repeat.

```
<ul ng-repeat='item in items'
       ng-switch-on='item.type'>
       <li ng-switch-when="type1" your desired attributes >
            Inner HTML
       </li>
       <li ng-switch-when="type2" your desired attributes >
            Inner HTML
       </li>
       <li ng-switch-when="type3" your desired attributes >
            Inner HTML
       </li>
</ul>
```